# ERROR org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: createTopics (kafka.admin.TopicCommand$)

Tags: apache-kafka

while I tried creating a topic, the error occur with a neumorously long error message

the part of whole message

```
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$CachedAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:952)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1663)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1528)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.DefaultHostResolver.resolve(DefaultHostResolver.java:27)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.resolve(ClientUtils.java:110)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClusterConnectionStates$NodeConnectionState.currentAddress(ClusterConnectionStates.java:510)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClusterConnectionStates$NodeConnectionState.access$200(ClusterConnectionStates.java:467)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClusterConnectionStates.currentAddress(ClusterConnectionStates.java:173)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.initiateConnect(NetworkClient.java:990)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.ready(NetworkClient.java:301)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.sendEligibleCalls(KafkaAdminClient.java:1143)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.processRequests(KafkaAdminClient.java:1403)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.run(KafkaAdminClient.java:1346)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
[2023-02-12 20:07:10,501] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Error connecting to node test-broker01:9092 (id: 1 rack: null) (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
java.net.UnknownHostException: test-broker01
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$CachedAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:952)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1663)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1528)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.DefaultHostResolver.resolve(DefaultHostResolver.java:27)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.resolve(ClientUtils.java:110)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClusterConnectionStates$NodeConnectionState.currentAddress(ClusterConnectionStates.java:510)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClusterConnectionStates$NodeConnectionState.access$200(ClusterConnectionStates.java:467)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClusterConnectionStates.currentAddress(ClusterConnectionStates.java:173)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.initiateConnect(NetworkClient.java:990)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.ready(NetworkClient.java:301)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.sendEligibleCalls(KafkaAdminClient.java:1143)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.processRequests(KafkaAdminClient.java:1403)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.run(KafkaAdminClient.java:1346)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
[2023-02-12 20:07:10,507] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Error connecting to node test-broker03:9092 (id: 3 rack: null) (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
java.net.UnknownHostException: test-broker03
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$CachedAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:952)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1663)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1528)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.DefaultHostResolver.resolve(DefaultHostResolver.java:27)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.resolve(ClientUtils.java:110)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClusterConnectionStates$NodeConnectionState.currentAddress(ClusterConnectionStates.java:510)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClusterConnectionStates$NodeConnectionState.access$200(ClusterConnectionStates.java:467)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClusterConnectionStates.currentAddress(ClusterConnectionStates.java:173)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.initiateConnect(NetworkClient.java:990)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.ready(NetworkClient.java:301)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.sendEligibleCalls(KafkaAdminClient.java:1143)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.processRequests(KafkaAdminClient.java:1403)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.run(KafkaAdminClient.java:1346)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
Error while executing topic command : Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: createTopics
```

The command I use is `./kafka-topics --create --bootstrap-server ip1:9092,ip2:9092,ip3:9092 --replication-factor 3 --partitions 1 --topic test`

**Environment**
zookeeper(3.8.1), broker(3.4.0) server : ec2 t2.micro linux 
local(where I tried creating topic) : mac os, kafka:3.3.2

**the broker server start message**
myid 3

```
kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient)
[2023-02-12 11:18:24,750] INFO Registered broker 3 at path /brokers/ids/3 with addresses: PLAINTEXT://test-broker03:9092, czxid (broker epoch): 21474836595 (kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient)
[2023-02-12 11:18:24,958] INFO [ExpirationReaper-3-topic]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
[2023-02-12 11:18:24,985] INFO [ExpirationReaper-3-Heartbeat]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
[2023-02-12 11:18:24,992] INFO [ExpirationReaper-3-Rebalance]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
[2023-02-12 11:18:25,031] INFO [GroupCoordinator 3]: Starting up. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2023-02-12 11:18:25,045] INFO [GroupCoordinator 3]: Startup complete. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2023-02-12 11:18:25,098] INFO [TransactionCoordinator id=3] Starting up. (kafka.coordinator.transaction.TransactionCoordinator)
[2023-02-12 11:18:25,108] INFO [TransactionCoordinator id=3] Startup complete. (kafka.coordinator.transaction.TransactionCoordinator)
[2023-02-12 11:18:25,112] INFO [Transaction Marker Channel Manager 3]: Starting (kafka.coordinator.transaction.TransactionMarkerChannelManager)
[2023-02-12 11:18:25,232] INFO [ExpirationReaper-3-AlterAcls]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
[2023-02-12 11:18:25,309] INFO [/config/changes-event-process-thread]: Starting (kafka.common.ZkNodeChangeNotificationListener$ChangeEventProcessThread)
[2023-02-12 11:18:25,317] INFO [SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=3] Enabling request processing. (kafka.network.SocketServer)
[2023-02-12 11:18:25,349] INFO Kafka version: 3.4.0 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2023-02-12 11:18:25,349] INFO Kafka commitId: 2e1947d240607d53 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2023-02-12 11:18:25,349] INFO Kafka startTimeMs: 1676200705333 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2023-02-12 11:18:25,358] INFO [KafkaServer id=3] started (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2023-02-12 11:18:25,570] INFO [BrokerToControllerChannelManager broker=3 name=forwarding]: Recorded new controller, from now on will use node test-broker01:9092 (id: 1 rack: null) (kafka.server.BrokerToControllerRequestThread)
[2023-02-12 11:18:25,602] INFO [BrokerToControllerChannelManager broker=3 name=alterPartition]: Recorded new controller, from now on will use node test-broker01:9092 (id: 1 rack: null) (kafka.server.BrokerToControllerRequestThread)
```

myid 2

```
[2023-02-12 11:18:25,739] INFO [SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=2] Enabling request processing. (kafka.network.SocketServer)
[2023-02-12 11:18:25,754] INFO Kafka version: 3.4.0 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2023-02-12 11:18:25,758] INFO Kafka commitId: 2e1947d240607d53 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2023-02-12 11:18:25,758] INFO Kafka startTimeMs: 1676200705744 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2023-02-12 11:18:25,759] INFO [KafkaServer id=2] started (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2023-02-12 11:18:25,921] INFO [BrokerToControllerChannelManager broker=2 name=forwarding]: Recorded new controller, from now on will use node test-broker01:9092 (id: 1 rack: null) (kafka.server.BrokerToControllerRequestThread)
[2023-02-12 11:18:25,939] INFO [BrokerToControllerChannelManager broker=2 name=alterPartition]: Recorded new controller, from now on will use node test-broker01:9092 (id: 1 rack: null) (kafka.server.BrokerToControllerRequestThread)
```

myid 1

```
[2023-02-12 11:18:25,739] INFO [SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=2] Enabling request processing. (kafka.network.SocketServer)
[2023-02-12 11:18:25,754] INFO Kafka version: 3.4.0 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2023-02-12 11:18:25,758] INFO Kafka commitId: 2e1947d240607d53 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2023-02-12 11:18:25,758] INFO Kafka startTimeMs: 1676200705744 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2023-02-12 11:18:25,759] INFO [KafkaServer id=2] started (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2023-02-12 11:18:25,921] INFO [BrokerToControllerChannelManager broker=2 name=forwarding]: Recorded new controller, from now on will use node test-broker01:9092 (id: 1 rack: null) (kafka.server.BrokerToControllerRequestThread)
[2023-02-12 11:18:25,939] INFO [BrokerToControllerChannelManager broker=2 name=alterPartition]: Recorded new controller, from now on will use node test-broker01:9092 (id: 1 rack: null) (kafka.server.BrokerToControllerRequestThread)
```

Is it actually success message?

If you need more information(zoo.cfg, server.properties etc.), question me please

Comment: try to remove the extra colon ":" in your command when specifying ip2:
`/kafka-topics --create --bootstrap-server ip1:9092,ip2:9092,ip3:9092 --replication-factor 3 --partitions 1 --topic test`

Comment: oh sorry it's just typo only in this writing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is saying that, from your Mac, it is unable to resolve the DNS names of your EC2 instances. You will need to provide the public DNS names of those VMs. To reproduce the error, you can simply `ping` those addresses ; your error has nothing to do with Kafka / Zookeeper.

Otherwise, I suggest using AWS MSK over running your own EC2 micros, which really aren't equipped enough to run Kafka very well.

Comment: ```ping``` doesn't reproduce the error but thanks to your advice ** from your Mac, it is unable to resolve the DNS names of your EC2 instances.** I edit /etc/hosts on mac too(only on ec2 previously) and it create topic well.